# Setup samba share from OS X terminal command line

Tags: macos, command-line, network-shares, samba

Having issues with my Mac's HDD.  Disk Utility is unable to repair it.  However, I can browse and read files from the OS X volume just fine.  I have a Time Machine backup from a week ago, but I don't like putting all my eggs in one basket, so thought I'd do an additional backup of the data since it is still readable.

I can connect to my wifi network fine when booting from the Snow Leopard DVD.  And I can write to my 16Gb USB fine.  But my other computer is Win7, which means having to use FAT32 formatted USB, which means no large files.

Anyway, since I have a network connection, I'd like to just grab the data over the network.

So how do I setup a samba (i.e. Windows readable) network share from the Terminal in OS X Snow Leopard?

EDIT: Just to clarify - I want to *create* a samba share on the OS X computer, not mount a samba share from another computer.

Answer (score 1):

I was going to point you to [this page](http://docs.huihoo.com/darwin/opendarwin/articles/osx_smb/ar01s03.html) describing how to set up samba shares on OS X, but you can set up samba shares through the System Preferences > Sharing panel.

Is it necessary to set it up through the Terminal? If not, [this Apple Help document](http://docs.info.apple.com/article.html?path=Mac/10.6/en/8201.html) will do the trick.

Comment: Yes - because I am booting from the DVD because my hard drive crashed.  I only get the limited functionality provided there, among which is the Terminal and network access.

Comment: @Matt Ah! I see. Personally, I'd consider using scp to "push" the files, possibly compressing them first… (PuTTY is an excellent Windows client) rather than the hassle of configuring a share.

Comment: scp can connect to windows? I've used putty *from* windows before, but never *to*

Answer (score 1):

SMB services are provided by `smbd`. `smbd` is configured by `/etc/smb.conf`. The configuration file uses an ini-style arrangement of `[section]` and `key = value`. You can get help on the syntax by `man smb.conf`. For example, to share `/` (the root directory) with a share name of "DYING", you would add the stanza:

```
[DYING]
path = /
read only = yes
guest ok = yes
```

The file will be reloaded by `smbd` on the minute. You can force a restart by sending `SIGHUP` to the daemon.